# First item on Custom BaseAdapter doesn't show up at Gridview and ClickListener on Gridview doesn't work

Tags: android, gridview, android-sqlite, baseadapter, android-cursor

I have been sitting for two days just to search and find what is wrong with the code of my fragment's gridview and adapter. the first item doesn't show up on my grid view.

This is my fragment code

```
public class FragmentConsumerHomeCanteen extends Fragment {

    private final String TAG = "ConsumerHomeCanteen";
    private GridView fchCanGrid;
    private ArrayList<CanteenRecordDetails> canteenRecordDetailsArrayList;
    private CanteenAdapter canteenAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_consumer_home_canteen, container, false);

        resourceVariables(view);

        canteenRecordDetailsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        canteenRecordDetailsArrayList.clear();
        CafeTreydDatabase cafeTreydDatabase = new CafeTreydDatabase(getActivity());
        Cursor cursor = cafeTreydDatabase.getCanteenForConsumerHomeCanteen(TAG);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                int id = cursor.getInt(0);
                String name = cursor.getString(1);
                String open = cursor.getString(2);
                String close = cursor.getString(3);
                byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(4);

                canteenRecordDetailsArrayList.add(new CanteenRecordDetails(id, name, open, close, image));
                canteenAdapter = new CanteenAdapter(getActivity(), canteenRecordDetailsArrayList);
                canteenAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            fchCanGrid.setAdapter(canteenAdapter);
            Log.i(TAG, "Setting adapter to GridView Successful");
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Cursor returns null");
        }

        return view;
    }

    private void resourceVariables(View view) {
        fchCanGrid = view.findViewById(R.id.fchCanGrid);
        Log.i(TAG, "Resourcing Successful");
    }

    private static class CanteenRecordDetails {

        private int id;
        private String name;
        private String open;
        private String close;
        private byte[] image;

        private CanteenRecordDetails(int id, String name, String open, String close, byte[] image) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.open = open;
            this.close = close;
            this.image = image;
        }

        private int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        private String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        private String getOpen() {
            return open;
        }

        private String getClose() {
            return close;
        }

        private byte[] getImage() {
            return image;
        }

    }

    private static class CanteenAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        private final Context context;
        private final ArrayList<CanteenRecordDetails> canteenRecordDetailsArrayList;
        private final LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        private CanteenAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CanteenRecordDetails> canteenRecordDetailsArrayList) {
            this.context = context;
            this.canteenRecordDetailsArrayList = canteenRecordDetailsArrayList;
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return canteenRecordDetailsArrayList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return canteenRecordDetailsArrayList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragment_consumer_home_canteen, parent, false);
            }
            LinearLayout lfchcLL = convertView.findViewById(R.id.lfchCanLL);
            TextView lfchCanName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.lfchCanName);
            TextView lfchCanOpen = convertView.findViewById(R.id.lfchCanOpen);
            TextView lfchCanClose = convertView.findViewById(R.id.lfchCanClose);
            ImageView lfchCanImage = convertView.findViewById(R.id.lfchCanImage);

            CanteenRecordDetails canteenRecordDetails = canteenRecordDetailsArrayList.get(position);
            lfchCanName.setText(canteenRecordDetails.getName());
            lfchCanOpen.setText(String.format("OPEN: %s", canteenRecordDetails.getOpen()));
            lfchCanClose.setText(String.format("CLOSE: %s", canteenRecordDetails.getClose()));
            byte[] tempImage = canteenRecordDetails.getImage();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(tempImage, 0, tempImage.length);
            lfchCanImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            lfchcLL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, lfchCanName.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    String TAG = "ConsumerHomeCanteen";
                    try {
                        ((ActivityConsumerHome)context).setCanteenId(canteenRecordDetails.getId());
                        ((ActivityConsumerHome)context).setCanteenName(canteenRecordDetails.getName());
                        Navigation.findNavController(parent).navigate(R.id.action_fragmentConsumerHomeCanteen_to_fragmentConsumerHomeCategory);
                        Log.i(TAG, "Navigating to next Fragment");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.i(TAG, "Failed to set canteenId");
                    }
                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

If you notice, I placed the `onclickListener` for the layout inside `getView` in the adapter because I can't use the `onItemClickListener` on `GridView`. it is not working. whatever solution I see on the internet, it doesn't work.

`gridview` still skips the first item on the adapter. I used info log to make sure that the database and `arraylist` work fine. It works fine. It's just the `griview` that has a problem I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:** The cursor moves to the first item using `cursor.moveToFirst()`, and then before catching the first item/row, you call `cursor.moveToNext()` in the `while` block below. And that makes you to go to the second item/row before having a chance to add the first to the adapter.

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int id = cursor.getInt(0);
        String name = cursor.getString(1);
        String open = cursor.getString(2);
        String close = cursor.getString(3);
        byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(4);

        canteenRecordDetailsArrayList.add(new CanteenRecordDetails(id, name, open, close, image));
        canteenAdapter = new CanteenAdapter(getActivity(), canteenRecordDetailsArrayList);
        canteenAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    fchCanGrid.setAdapter(canteenAdapter);
    Log.i(TAG, "Setting adapter to GridView Successful");
} else {
    Log.i(TAG, "Cursor returns null");
}
```

**Solution:**

You need to execute the code inside the `while` block before calling `cursor.moveToNext()`

Use `do/while` instead of `while` So that the iterated code runs before checking the `while` condition

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        int id = cursor.getInt(0);
        String name = cursor.getString(1);
        String open = cursor.getString(2);
        String close = cursor.getString(3);
        byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(4);

        canteenRecordDetailsArrayList.add(new CanteenRecordDetails(id, name, open, close, image));
        canteenAdapter = new CanteenAdapter(getActivity(), canteenRecordDetailsArrayList);
        canteenAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    
    fchCanGrid.setAdapter(canteenAdapter);
    Log.i(TAG, "Setting adapter to GridView Successful");
} else {
    Log.i(TAG, "Cursor returns null");
}
```

Comment: Oh. i guess that is why, when i do this code in cursor

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        .........
}

it Logs info of the first record but not included in the adapter. i sometimes try to do test to check where the logical error lands at but im getting nothing. this really helps a lot. Thanks!!!!!

Comment: @VonCaraig glad to hear that :) happy coding